# Logic apps in a multi tenant environment

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

We are planning to build a SFTP connector using logic apps which will basically take a file uploaded to azure blob and upload it to a sftp location. 
We are SaaS product and are dealing with multiple customers. Also we have storage accounts per customer or tenant.

My questions is how would this logic app should be Deployed
1.  should it be a single logic app which can listen to multiple storage accounts and upload the files .Right now I cant figure out how this can be done.
2. Should it be a logic app / tenant configured one to one with the storage account of the tenant

I would like to know what is the usual  pattern followed in a multi-tenant environment and are their any pros / cons of deploying a logic app / tenant.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create one Logic App per tenant. What you could do is to create an API connection per storage account (per tenant). You could do it with [ARM Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/connections) and Azure CLI. You could give the API connection an Id based on your tenantId

Then, in your Logic App workflow you can chose at run time the API connection dynamically, depending on the tenant Id.

e.g.

```
"Get_blob_content": {
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "/subscriptions/<id>/resourceGroups/<id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/@{variables('tenantId')}"
            }
        },
        "method": "get",
        "path": "/datasets/default/files/.../content",
        "queries": {
            "inferContentType": true
        }
    },
    "metadata": {
        "...": "..."
    },
    "runAfter": {},
    "type": "ApiConnection"
}
```

It would be up to you to decide how to name the API Connection, how to get it at runtime, and how to get the full connectionId at runtime. But hopefully you get the idea of what you can do the code above.

HTH

Comment: Great. Thanks looks like this approach can work. I'll try this as we already use ARM templates for deployment

Comment: That would only work in cases where you are storing the tenants credentials, correct?

Comment: Can you show me how I set dynamic value for already developed logic app? If any documentation or example link available it is very useful.

Comment: @anomepani, there are some tips documented here https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd

Comment: @PacodelaCruz, Yes I have reviewed,I am unsure about how to set dynamic connections for Microsoft Teams, AzureCosmosDb, Event Grid and Blob Storage for Multi-Tenant or cross tenant scenario. Finding way to use with CI CD Pipelines.